# Multiply two values from same textbox separated by Symbol and display result in other textbox

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose I've entered value in single textbox like 5*5 then next box should display 25. is it possible??

Comment: Yes, it is possible by using jQuery.

Comment: can you provide some link or demo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have 2 text boxes as below

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="" onblur="evalthevalue(this.value, 'text2')" />
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function evalthevalue(inputVal, idToReplace)
{
    console.log('inputVal'+inputVal);
    console.log('idToReplace'+idToReplace);
    console.log('eval'+eval(inputVal.trim()));

document.getElementById(idToReplace).value = eval(inputVal.trim());
}
</script>
```

The consoles are for testing the inputs, you can remove if you are able to achieve that. This is now tested at my end. Thanks

Comment: i'm taking both values in single textbox, we need to separate them first and then multiply!!

Comment: Please check my above answer, I have edited it as per your need. The consoles are for testing the inputs, you can remove if you are able to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: superb!! thanks a lot!! worked fine!!

Answer (score 3):

Let textbox 1 id be "t1" and textbox 2 id be "t2"

```
document.getElementById("t2").value = eval(document.getElementById("t1").value);
```

Comment: sorry, but it's not working!!

Comment: use <input type="text" id="t1" /> and <input type="text" id="t2" />

Comment: or change the id "t1" and "t2" accordingly in script

Comment: after let me know if it worked or not

Comment: i'm taking both values in single textbox, we need to separate them first and then multiply!!

Comment: no need. eval automatically do it.
if you put `eval(5*5);` It will automatically 25

Comment: @shyamm : don't   say you are taking 2 values in same field. We first read the question and then only give answer. We are doing these much and you don't even check whether it works or not and say such stupidity. Check whether it works or not

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want to archive.

```
var calculation = {
    '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
};
```

Add any calculation like this

```
'+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
'-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
```

```js
document.getElementById('doit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var twoVal = document.getElementById('two').value.trim();
  if (twoVal.indexOf('*') !== -1) {
    var items = twoVal.split('*');
    document.getElementById('one').value = calculation['*'](items[0], items[1]);
  }
})
var calculation = {
  '*': function(x, y) {
    return x * y
  },
};
```

```html
<input id="two" type="text" value="3*10">
<input id="one" type="text">
<button type="button" id="doit">Do it</button>
```

Comment: perfect answer!